# Float Issue with Masonry grid

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to format a masonry grid, I can't seem to get the items to clear to go up below the other items. I've tried many other ways to get this to be the way i want it to be. Any help would be appreciated.
This is what i'm trying to accomplish
[image: 1]

and this is what i'm seeing
[image: 2]

```css
<style>
.gridywrap div[class*=gridy] {
  padding: 15px; float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
.gridywrap .gridy-1,
.gridywrap .gridy-2,
.gridywrap .gridy-3 {
  width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gridywrap .gridy-1 {width: 100%;}
.gridywrap .gridy-2 {width: 100%;}
.gridywrap .gridy-3 {width: 100%;}

.gridywrap .gridyhe-1 {height: 284px;}
.gridywrap .gridyhe-1-5 {height: 284px;}
.gridywrap .gridyhe-2 {height: 320px;}
.gridywrap .gridyhe-1-3 {height: 284px;}


@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .gridywrap .gridyhe-2 {height: 320px;}
  .gridywrap {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .gridywrap .gridy-1 {width: 50%;}
  .gridywrap .gridy-2 {width: 50%;}
  .gridywrap .gridy-3 {width: 100%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .gridywrap .gridy-1 {width: 297px;}
  .gridywrap .gridy-1-5 {width: 25%;}
  .gridywrap .gridyhe-1-3 {width: 607px;}
  .gridywrap .gridy-2 {width: 66.6%;}
  .gridywrap .gridy-3 {width: 100%;}
  .gridywrap .gridyhe-2 {height: 578px;}
}

/*styling*/
.gridywrap .gridimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.gridywrap .gridimg img {
  width: 100%;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 130px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo h3:after {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .gridmeta {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .gridmeta p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .gridmeta p i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .gridmeta p.gridwho {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo p.gridexerpt {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.gridywrap .gridinfo * {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .grid-btn {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #fff; 
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .grid-btn:hover {
  width: 75px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .grid-btn span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .grid-btn:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo .grid-btn:hover i {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.gridywrap .gridinfo:hover * {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo:hover {
  background: rgba(158, 12, 73, 0.7);
}
.gridywrap .gridinfo:hover h3 {
  // margin-top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="gridywrap">
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-2">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/Yosemite\ Backpacking-TuolumneMeadows-DamianRiley\ \(280\)_RT.png)">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Clark Kent</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-5">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/Screen\ Shot\ 2020-07-14\ at\ 9.57.05\ AM@2x.png)">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Steve Rogers</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-3">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/uploads/1411589183965bdf6e141/5f468e98?q=75&fm=jpg&s=007333c388fb36767cbd152600bea6b8)">&nbsp;</div>
        
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Natasha Romanoff</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-5">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1418227165283-1595d13726cd?q=75&fm=jpg&s=cace1590a29be6d4d6db13c3ebd1ba72)">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Steve Rogers</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-5">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1418227165283-1595d13726cd?q=75&fm=jpg&s=cace1590a29be6d4d6db13c3ebd1ba72)">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Steve Rogers</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-2">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416934625760-d56f5e79f6fe?q=75&fm=jpg&s=032ca37757b3dc1851661856b956a24c)">&nbsp;</div>
        
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Clark Kent</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-5">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1418227165283-1595d13726cd?q=75&fm=jpg&s=cace1590a29be6d4d6db13c3ebd1ba72)">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Steve Rogers</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridy-1 gridyhe-1-3">
        <div class="gridimg" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/uploads/1411589183965bdf6e141/5f468e98?q=75&fm=jpg&s=007333c388fb36767cbd152600bea6b8)">&nbsp;</div>
        
        <div class="gridinfo">
          <h3>Item Title</h3>
          <div class="gridmeta">
            <p class="gridwhen"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 17:22 17th Feb 2015</p>
            <p class="gridwho"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Natasha Romanoff</p>
          </div>
          <p class="gridexerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet, some dummy content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="grid-btn grid-more"><span>More</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```